# How to work on a website which is selected as down mode?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I use Laravel framework and as you know there is a something named [Maintenance Mode](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#maintenance-mode). That's perfect for debugging the online version of your website. I mean, you can simply deactivate your website to open by this command:

```
php artisan down
```

Also you can make it alive again by this one:

```
php artisan up
```

Ok all fine .. My question is, how can I see the result of debugging on my website in this case? I mean, when my website is `down` for my website's user, I need to load it and do some tests on it .. but sadly it is also `down` for me.

Anyway, I'm looking for an approach to shut down my website for everybody **except myself**. Any idea?

Comment: Why not just set up a testing environment somewhere and, when you're done making changes there, update the site?

Answer (score 0):

Create a local development environment, preferably with something like [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) or [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet).

Basic rule of thumb on the internet: if you can see it, someone else can.

The local environment also gives you the benefit that should you mess something up, no end user will experience that.